# Red gate SQL Compare error while running using SQL Agent Job

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent, sqlcompare

I created a SQL agent job to perform a SQL Compare using the below command line

```
powershell.exe -File D:\SQLCompareReports\DEVvsPRJ\DEVvsPRJ.ps1
```

This below given is the command line code in DEVvsPRJ.ps1 file

```
set-location "C:\Program Files (x86)\Red Gate\SQL Compare 13";
./sqlcompare /s1:Server1 /db1:Database1/s2:Server2 /db2:Database2/r:"D:\SQLCompareReports\DEVvsPRJ\DEVvsPRJ.html" /rt:Classic /f
```

So, when I tried executing the job it succeeded without any errors. But when I checked the location comparison report was not created. So I went back to Job history and found the following error.

> ========  Copyright Copyright c Red Gate Software Ltd 2019 Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is
>   denied.     at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String
>   maybeFullPath)     at
>   System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream.Connect(Int32 timeout)     at
>   RedGate.Ipc.NamedPipes.NamedPipeEndpointClient.Connect(Int32
>   timeoutMs)     at
>   RedGate.Ipc.Rpc.RpcConnectionProvider.TryGetConnection(TimeSpan
>   timeout)     at
>   RedGate.Ipc.ReconnectingConnectionProvider.ReconnectionWorker()     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
>   preserveSyncCtx)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart().  Process Exit Code 0. 
>   The step succeeded.

Can anyone please suggest me a way on how to automate this task or a way through this error.

Comment: The error is quite clear: `Access to the path is denied. ` -- check to see if the directory is writeable by the ultimate user that is executing the script

Comment: Why don't you run this as a powershell job instead of adding all these additional layers?

Comment: @Philᵀᴹ Yes, the account has full control over the directory.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I tried running the PowerShell job but I was getting the following errors:The job script encountered the following errors. These errors did not stop the script:  A job step received an error at line 2 in a PowerShell script. 
The corresponding line is './sqlcompare /s1:Server1 /db1:Database1 /s2:Server2 /db2:Database2 /r:"D:\SQLCompareReports\DEVvsPRJ\DEVvsPRJ.html" /rt:Classic /f'. 
Correct the script and reschedule the job.

Comment: Which account? Are you sure you checked the account that the SQL Server Agent job is running as? How did you validate this? Is D:\ a mapped drive? Mapped to who? Also you should be able to troubleshoot the error you are getting from powershell even before introducing this to Agent - SQL Server isn't going to make that error go away.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, yes I validated the account.Sql agent account is mapped to the drive. When I run the same script in PowerShell terminal it works perfectly fine. I get this issue only when I try running it in SQL agent job.

Comment: When you run the same script in PowerShell terminal **as you**, or when you run the same script in PowerShell terminal **as the SQL Agent account**? Big difference. What is the SQL Server service / SQL Server Agent service account(s)? How are you running PowerShell terminal **as that account**? SQL Server doesn't just make up "Access to the path is denied" errors, it's likely because the agent account doesn't have access, and you're not verifying that for that specific account.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I have created a proxy account to run the PowerShell script using SQL agent and with the same account, I tried running script in PS terminal. I am not using a service account for running any PS script.

Answer (score 1):

Since I did not get a proper solution to this using the SQL Agent job, I had to try an alternative.

I used Windows Task Scheduler to run this. I have saved my script as DEVvsPRJ.ps1 and invoked PowerShell using the scheduler and it worked fine.

Running the Powershell script in scheduler solved the problem.